# go test unexpectedly passes -test.timeout flag to program under test

Tags: unit-testing, go

I have a small cli program in `go` that implements one command line flag (`-config=<config file>`) using `flag.String()`.

When I call `go test` it errors out because my program says `flag provided but not defined: -test.timeout`.

`go test -v -x -args -config=./config.yml` gives me:

```
/usr/lib/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/link -o $WORK/b001/...  .../b001/myprogram.test -test.timeout=10m0s -test.v=true -config=./config.yml
```

In other words, it passes the test arguments on to `myprogram`, even though I expect this to be inhibited by the `-args` flag (should only pass arguments *after* the `-args` flag?).

Is this a bug, resp. is there a way to inhibit `go test` from passing any flags to the tested program other than the ones I specifically tell it to)?

EDIT:
The relevant code snippet:

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "encoding/json"
    "flag"
    // ...
)

// ...

var (
    configpath = flag.String("config", "config.yml", "Config file to use, if omitted defaults to config.yml")
    // ...

func init() {
    var err error
    flag.Parse()
    _, err = configGlobal.getConfig(*configpath)
    if err != nil {
        panic("No config loaded")
    }
    // ...
}
```

Normally running the program without arguments or with the argument `-config ./config.yml` works, obviously passing other flags doesn't.

Comment: It's not passing them to `myprogram`, it's passing them to `myprogram.test` which is the test binary. The `test.x` flags will be consumed by the testing code. Can you show some of your test code, and where you configure your flags.

Comment: @Marc Thanks, of course it is, my mistake! Somehow the dedicated test (`myprogram_test.go`) disappeared from the repo, ( resp. was broken down to sub-tests by a fellow programmer ;). So it appears we should be calling test more specifically or add a main test definition.